# Run npm start in Atom Text Editor

Tags: atom-editor

In [Atom](http://atom.io) text editor, after saving a file, I'd like to have a hotkey like **ctrl-alt-b** that will run **"npm build"** and display the results in an embedded terminal.

I'm also hoping that after seeing the terminal output, I'd be able to click anywhere outside that embedded terminal to make it go away, (instead of having to mouse-travel to some small exit button and click it).

It may be relevant to mention that my OS is Ubuntu 16.04.5.

I did find a really nice tool called the [atom build package](https://atom.io/packages/build), but it seems to take over the whole build process, which is something I've already got setup via "npm build".

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a hotkey is the trivial part, but you need some package that provides the actual build command. You can add something like the following to your Atom keymap:

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-alt-b': 'package-name:command-name'
```

Other than that, I recommend using a general purpose package like [`process-palette`](https://atom.io/packages/process-palette). It lets you define a command (or a chain of commands) and run it in your project directory at the press of a custom hotkey.